# Reload function, not page: Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
 <head>

  <center><p id="final"></p></center>


  <script>
  var currentDay = new Date();
  var breakStart = new Date(2017, 3, 21, 15, 20);
  var breakEnd = new Date(2017, 4, 1, 8, 40);
  var difference = (breakStart.getTime() - currentDay.getTime())/1000;


days = Math.floor(difference / 86400)
difference %= 86400;
hours = Math.floor(difference / 3600)
difference %= 3600;
minutes = Math.floor(difference / 60)
difference %= 60;
seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1)
difference %= 1;

function refresh(){
  document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = ("There are " + days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, and " + seconds + " seconds left until spring break.")
  refresh();
  }
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.reload(1);
     }, 951);

  </script>
```

This program I wrote for class lets you know when spring break will begin. I have extensively looked for a solution to my problem. My problem is that I need to reload the function "refresh()", not the entire page. Even my crazy coding buddy couldn't figure it out. If you remove the function it works. I simply put the function there trying to find a way to refresh it.

Anything helps,
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "reload"? It sounds like you just want to call the function.

Comment: So basically you want to update the time left displayed on the page, without reloading the page ?

Comment: What I mean is that I want the function to re-display the variables and text over and over so that people can see the countdown until spring break.

Comment: Exactly adeneo.

Comment: It's amazingly simple -> **https://jsfiddle.net/km6kmhv4/**

Comment: How did I not find this solution!? Thanks so much. I feel like a dingus now.